I can’t start the Docker container, error ‘mkdocs.yaml’ does not exist
I'm new to using Docker, I saw that it was just to generate the image and upload the container. But every time I'm going to do this an error comes up:
2024-06-10 22:04:40 Error: Config file 'mkdocs.yml' does not exist.

The created image is based on this repository:
https://github.com/dhkatz/imvu.js
To create the image I use the commands:
docker build -t imvu-client ./docs

After that, I start the container, using Docker desktop itself.
I saw in a GitHub forum that it might be an environment variable error in squidfunk/mkdocs-material. But there isn't much information on how to fix it.
Possible resolution: https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/discussions/4235
As I said, I'm new to Docker, I have no idea what is causing the problem and I can't find any easy-to-understand resolution:
System:
Windows 11
Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics            3.00 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (usable: 7.42 GB)

What does your Dockerfile look like? You probably need to bindmount the directory containing the mkdocs.yml file, or copy it.

@SathyajithBhat Okay, copy where specifically? I've already tried putting the mkdocs.yml in the folder where the dockerfile is, but the error continues
